# Quasar QForm not submitting when the Vee-validation ValidationProvider is used on q-input

Tags: quasar-framework, vee-validate, quasar

I have a form in Quasar:

```
<q-form @submit="onSubmit">
  <ValidationProvider
    rules="required"
    v-slot="{ errors, invalid, validated }"
    slim
  >
    <q-input
      filled
      clearable
      v-model="login"
      type="login"
      label="Login"
      :error="invalid && validated"
      :error-message="errors[0]"
    />
  </ValidationProvider>
  <q-btn
    type="submit"
    color="primary"
    class="full-width"
    label="Login"
  />
</q-form>
```

And the method:

```
methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    console.log("submitting");
  }
}
```

And the method onSubmit is never called. If I delete ValidationProvider (and :error and :error-message on the field) it is working.

Why? How I’m supposed to be using Vee-validate then?

Thanks